# Correct a sentence which used 欲しがる

Tags: keigo, sonkeigo

This is only a simple correcting problem I encountered in a book.

社長さんは工場＿をご覧になりたがっています。＿

The part between "_" is the part that need to be corrected.

I've looked up some pages and saw multiple opinions about 尊敬語 of 欲しがる.

The one I agree to is that 欲しがる doesn't have a 尊敬語.

But how can I correct this sentence then..?(´･_･`)

I know that 欲しがる is rude in here but have no idea what word can I change it to.

Comment: I've put my final answer as 社長さんは工場の参観するのをご希望になっています。20 minutes ago when I submitted it.

Comment: Are you really aware of connotation of calling 社長さん instead of 社長? (If it's the case, I'm sorry.)

Comment: Yeah I know that, I just copied the sentence here without making any change. It does sound impolite tho.@user4092

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Weblio辞書](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%AC%B2%E3%81%97%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B) says it means either ほしいと思う or ほしそうなようすをする. Now, the latter definition can be further divided into either one that you really want something or one that you don't really want it but just pretend so.

In short, ほしがる is synonymous to either 1. ほしいと思う (to want), 2. 手に入れようとする (to try to obtain) or 3. ほしいふりをする (to pretend to want). However, the third one is so rare in practice that you usually use other words to express it.

So, you can make those paraphrases into each honorific form. i.e. 1. 見たいと思ってらっしる (or 工場の視察{しさつ}をご所望{しょもう}だ), 2. ご覧になろうとしている or 3. ご覧になるふりをなさっている.

This is parallel to how もらう's honorific form is not おもらいになる but お受け取りになる.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And I just realized 視察 may be the word that I was looking for cuz I was trying to use ご希望. But ご所望 makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

ご覧になりたいそうです。(Thanks @Shoko)
Would be ever polite enough.

Comment: From my grammar book I read that if you ever want to present the desire of a third person, you wanna use 欲しがる. But using 欲しがる would sound rude here..  Anyways, yeah thank you for your reply, that make sense to me. @stackreader